# Use OpenCV in a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile(KMM) project

Tags: opencv, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

### Setup:

We are currently using OpenCV on iOS and Android for image processing. On Android we import OpenCV as a `.aar` and on iOS we import it via Cocoapods, and they call the same underlying functions.

### Problem:

We would like to have a KMM project where we can import OpenCV and share the business logic. We are using `expect/actual` to depend on OpenCV in platform specific code.
We can make it work for Android by importing the same `.aar` in `androidMain`.
Our problem is with iOS. Currently KMM doesn't support interoperability with C++ (which OpenCV is written in) - see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/roadmap.html#removed-items

### What we have tried:

We tried to link a `.framework` via Gradle and create `.def` files to point to the `.hpp` files in OpenCV but we get an error `xxx.hpp header must be compiled as C++` when trying to sync Gradle.

`build.gradle.kts`

```
iosX64() {
    compilations.getByName("main") {
        val OpenCV by cinterops.creating {
            // Path to .def file
            defFile("src/iosMain/cinterop/OpenCV.def")

            // Directories for header search (an analogue of the -I<path> compiler option)
            includeDirs("../iosApp/Pods/OpenCV/opencv2.framework/Headers/Core")
        }
    }

    binaries.all {
        // Linker options required to link to the library.
        linkerOpts("-L/../iosApp/Pods/OpenCV/opencv2.framework", "-lopencv2")
    }
}
```

`OpenCV.def`

```
headers = cvstd.hpp
package = OpenCV
```

### Question:

Is there any way to depend on OpenCV in KMM?

Comment: Have you found a solution?